# Ajax calling in a function goes into abspath loop

Tags: plugin-development

I am calling wordpress file with Ajax call through Javascript. However the files goes into the loop

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 
{ echo 123;exit;}
```

And does not run further into it.

So please guide me solution for it.

Comment: What wordpress file?

Comment: my plugin file thatI have called

Comment: never access you plugins directly from the browser. Take an hour read a tutorial on how to do ajax in wordpress and follow it

Comment: I am calling ajax from java script only. But still I am getting that error

Comment: ABSPATH is only present when WordPress is loaded. You’re not loading WordPress because your hitting your file directly, which you’re not supposed to do. Do what Mark said and look into the proper way to do Ajax in WordPress.

Comment: Plugins are loaded before other parts of Wordpress